# Strange Sgt. Peppers red vinyl?

Tags: the-beatles

I bought a Sgt. Peppers Lonely Hearts Club Band vinyl record from an old bookshop. I bought it for €20 (euros) which is very close to what it would cost in both British Pounds and US dollars. I later discovered it was red and slightly translucent. The label says EMI Parlophone - stereo PCS. 7027 and made in 1970. The vinyl and sleeve feels, looks and sounds brand new. I was wondering if this is an original vinyl or just some random copy? Thanks. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYXDy.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but your description seems to match this release on [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Beatles-Sgt-Peppers-Lonely-Hearts-Club-Band/release/3188345):

> **Unofficial, UK; Repress from 2011**.
>   Red vinyl, Black/silver Parlophone label EMI boxed logos.

It seems to be a pirate release as is not allowed to be sold on this marketplace.

A forum about [Beatles Collecting](http://z10.invisionfree.com/BeatlesCollecting/index.php) have this [discussion](http://z10.invisionfree.com/BeatlesCollecting/index.php?s=80c6817328995789e8d00e1b46301cc2&showtopic=1153) in 2011:

> This UK version is probably a recent counterfeit/pirate or whatever you call it. Possibly one of countless recent coloured vinyl "reissues" that include many rare Beatles LPs from around the world.